# Python: Xlsxwriter, Save a file after first save failed

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Sometimes I am trying to save a xlsx workbook and I have the file open. I do a lot of processing before, so if the file save fails for something as simple as the worksheet being open, I have to run the whole script again.

Wanted to do something like this but it doesn't seem to save the new file, even when I close the old one and retry. I'm guessing this is something to do with the wb object going away.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
import xlsxwriter,datetime,time
wb=xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
ws=wb.add_worksheet('test')
ws.write_row(0,0,['aaaa',str(datetime.datetime.now())])
try:
    wb.close()
except IOError :
    print('save error, please close file, will retry in 10')
    time.sleep(10)
    wb.close()
```

Comment: Invert the problem? Try to open the file for write, if it fails pop-up the warning, then save when you are "sure" it's closed.

Answer (score 3):

From AIG's answer, this works great, Thank you:

```
wb=xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
ws=wb.add_worksheet('test')
ws.write_row(0,0,['aaaa',str(datetime.datetime.now())])
for i in range(3):
    try:
        test=open('test.xlsx','w')
    except IOError :
        if i!=2:
            print('save error')
            time.sleep(5)
try:
    wb.close()
except IOError:
    print('could not save file')
```